# Errors while running CTest with Eigen

Tags: c++, cmake, eigen

I have tried to install Eigen from `http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/`
INSTALL file explains how to make it with cmake.

```
  cd build_dir
  cmake source_dir
  make install
```

After the `make install`, I have tried `make test`.But all 651 examples failed.

```
621 - polynomialsolver_9 (Failed)
622 - polynomialsolver_10 (Failed)
623 - polynomialutils_2 (Failed)
624 - polynomialutils_3 (Failed)
625 - polynomialutils_4 (Failed)
626 - polynomialutils_5 (Failed)
627 - polynomialutils_6 (Failed)
628 - polynomialutils_7 (Failed)
629 - polynomialutils_8 (Failed)
630 - polynomialutils_9 (Failed)
631 - kronecker_product (Failed)
632 - splines (Failed)
633 - gmres_1 (Failed)
634 - gmres_2 (Failed)
635 - minres_1 (Failed)
636 - minres_2 (Failed)
637 - levenberg_marquardt (Failed)
638 - bdcsvd_11 (Failed)
639 - bdcsvd_13 (Failed)
640 - bdcsvd_14 (Failed)
641 - bdcsvd_15 (Failed)
642 - bdcsvd_16 (Failed)
643 - bdcsvd_17 (Failed)
644 - bdcsvd_18 (Failed)
645 - bdcsvd_3 (Failed)
646 - bdcsvd_4 (Failed)
647 - bdcsvd_7 (Failed)
648 - bdcsvd_8 (Failed)
649 - bdcsvd_1 (Failed)
650 - bdcsvd_2 (Failed)
651 - bdcsvd_5 (Failed)

Errors while running CTest
make: *** [test] Error 8
```

How to solve this problem?I am on Ubuntu 14.04.

```
Running tests...
Test project /home/milenko/softw/eigen-eigen-bdd17ee3b1b3/build_dir
        Start   1: meta
  1/651 Test   #1: meta .............................***Failed    0.01 sec
        Start   2: sizeof
  2/651 Test   #2: sizeof ...........................***Failed    0.01 sec
        Start   3: dynalloc
  3/651 Test   #3: dynalloc .........................***Failed    0.01 sec
        Start   4: nomalloc_1
  4/651 Test   #4: nomalloc_1 .......................***Failed    0.01 sec
        Start   5: nomalloc_2
  5/651 Test   #5: nomalloc_2 .......................***Failed    0.01 sec
        Start   6: nomalloc_3
  6/651 Test   #6: nomalloc_3 .......................***Failed    0.01 sec
        Start   7: nomalloc_4
  7/651 Test   #7: nomalloc_4 .......................***Failed    0.01 sec
        Start   8: nomalloc_5
  8/651 Test   #8: nomalloc_5 .......................***Failed    0.01 sec
        Start   9: nomalloc_6
  9/651 Test   #9: nomalloc_6 .......................***Failed    0.01 sec
        Start  10: first_aligned
 10/651 Test  #10: first_aligned ....................***Failed    0.01 sec
        Start  11: mixingtypes_1
 11/651 Test  #11: mixingtypes_1 ....................***Failed    0.01 sec
```

This is just part of the all examples,but all have failed.

Comment: That is not very informative. You have to provide more info. Can you make those tests more verbose?

Comment: For example what?I can add cmakelist.txt or...?

Comment: i think you need to build tests before running them. Take a look at the `buildtests.sh` script.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should build test as described [here](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Tests).

> make buildtests

Comment: Works after make buildtests.